# Is 'module' a globally accessible variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am trying to understand deeper how Node is actually working and I had a query about the following code

```
console.log(global.module)
console.log(module)
```

This is what was logged in the console

> undefined
> {
> id: '.',
> path: '/Users/danielsaleh/Desktop/NC/Sem-Playground/exports-and-require',
> exports: {},
> filename: '/Users/danielsaleh/Desktop/NC/Sem-Playground/exports-and-require/file1.js',
> loaded: false,
> children: [],
> paths: [
> '/Users/danielsaleh/Desktop/NC/Sem-Playground/exports-and-require/node_modules',
> '/Users/danielsaleh/Desktop/NC/Sem-Playground/node_modules',
> '/Users/danielsaleh/Desktop/NC/node_modules',
> '/Users/danielsaleh/Desktop/node_modules',
> '/Users/danielsaleh/node_modules',
> '/Users/node_modules',
> '/node_modules'
> ]
> }**

I guess I would just like to know, how I can access that 'module' variable if it doesn't exist on the global object? (apologies if this is a really basic question)

Comment: apologies on the formatting of the log :S

Comment: `module` refers to CommonJS. it's kinda outdated/legacy now, use ES modules in new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node.js, if you're using [CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules-commonjs-modules), node will automatically wrap your module in a wrapper function, see [The module wrapper](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#the-module-wrapper) section of the docs.

> Before a module's code is executed, Node.js will wrap it with a
> function wrapper that looks like the following:
>
> ```
> (function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { 
> // Module code actually lives in here
> });
> ```

This allows the code that you write in a CJS module to have access to the variable called `module`, as well as other "global-looking" variables such as `exports`, even though they don't exist on the global object `global`.